# How set properties enable on false for very textbox on form with extender provider. {C#, Winforms}

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 30 textbox and other control on winform, and I want sometimes set their properties (enable, visible) on true/false. I don’t make duplicate code. I am newbie in winforms, and I’d like know what is the good solution for this problem.
I’d like use extender provider, but I’d know if it is suitable. Sory for my english. :)

If someone can give me a code example, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

IExtenderProvider is not a suitable solution to this, it was meant to add new properties to existing controls.  The generic approach is quite simple: use a Panel.  Put all the controls you want to disable or hide in that panel.  And set the panel's Visible or Enabled property to false.  This will automatically disable all the child controls of the panel.  And when you hide the panel, its children will be hidden too.

Comment: Hans, he might be talking about having text boxes scattered on the form in different panels. If the design is not modifiable, what should be done? Recursive iteration into each container panel or something to work on text boxes in it?

Comment: That reminds me of a traffic sign I saw in Nevada.  The practice target for a double-barreled shotgun.

Comment: The controls are not on the same panel.

Comment: They are easy to move, click and drag.  Partition your user interface, avoid making it look like that Nevada traffic sign.  Considering creating a *new* one, another form, when the gun gets too big.  I don't doubt I'm telling you stuff you already knew.  No, using a bazooka doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situations when you want to toggle visibility and enable/disable status.
If you want to change the state, you can do something like:

```
private void ToggleVisible(TextBox tb)
{
  tb.Visible = !tb.Visible;
}
private void ToggleEnable(TextBox tb)
{
  tb.Enabled= !tb.Enabled;
}
```

Also if you want to update the status of multiple textboxes at the same time, you better define a method and do the batch updating for certain groups.
What really matters is to categorize (group) your textboxes properly. (into panels if you can)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done something like that:

In the base form class from which my forms inherit (which, in turn, inherits from Form)....

```
#region Form Fields Enablers

protected virtual void EnableFormFields(Control ctl)
{
  EnableFormFields(ctl, true);
}

protected virtual void DisableFormFields(Control ctl)
{
  EnableFormFields(ctl, false);
}

protected virtual void EnableFormFields(Control ctl, bool enable)
{
  EnableFormFields(ctl, enable, new string[0]);
}

protected virtual void EnableFormFields(Control ctl, bool enable, params string[] excludeControlName)
{
  bool exclude = false;
  foreach (string excludeCtl in excludeControlName)
  {
    if (string.Compare(ctl.Name, excludeCtl, true) == 0)
    {
      exclude = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!exclude)
  {
    ctl.Enabled = enable;
    foreach (Control childCtl in ctl.Controls)
    {
      EnableFormFields(childCtl, enable, excludeControlName);
    }
  }
}

#endregion  Form Fields Enablers
```

Then, in the particular form, I call `this.EnableFormFields(someContainerControl)` when I want to set all the controls within a given container, such as all controls on all tabs (tabcontrol) or all controls on a single tab (tabpage), or even all the controls on the form (passing "this"), etc.  I can even exclude some controls by passing their names as a string array, or each such name as a separate trailing parameter ("params" in the method definition's parameter list).

I think this is what John was seeking.  The important note for a newbie is the recursiveness of this code, setting the Enable property for a given control, then calling the method to set the Enable property in each of the control's child controls.  Each of these, in turn, set the property on their child controls.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to subclass the Textbox and add your own properties:

```
class MyTextbox : Textbox {
    public bool MyEnable {
        get{ return someBool; }
        set {
            if (yourConditionIsMet) {
                someBool = value;
                this.Enabled = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...then iterate over all your controls in your form:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls) {
    if (control is MyTextbox)
        control.MyEnable = true;
}
```